# How to trigger onClick before href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to do some functionality in `onClick()` event and also doing the `href` for the same element. But actually happening is its not triggering `onClick()` completely and its moving to `href` link when we click that element.

How to make `onClick()` gets complete first and trigger `href` next.

```
<a href="" onclick="javascript:triggerMe()">click</a>
```

Comment: `onclick` *does* trigger first, the `href` only goes once `onclick` has returned! Are you doing something asynchronous in the `onclick` and you want to wait until it returns or something? Please post onclick code...

Comment: @Shai - Those must be the 2 most similar comments talking the same thing in so many words.. :-) Deleting mine as you've got the point across..

Comment: @techfoobar I actually copied you, 7 seconds early

Comment: onclick = test();

function test() { log.data() }

Comment: What does `log.data()` do?

Comment: It will log data dear.. google analytics..

Comment: I have edited my code it will surely work.

Comment: Sounds asynchronous to me... you'll have to put a `return false;` in your click handler, which will prevent the `href` from firing at all, then when `log.data()` completes (should hopefully take a callback), manually send the user to the `href` page (or remove your JS onclick handler and then trigger a re-click on the element). If you don't know how to do that, post your full code and we should be able to help.

Comment: @VinothBabu I've found you a Google Analytics article that gives instructions on how to do this (they actually just use a 100ms delay and assume that the tracking will have completed by then): https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

Answer (score 9):

As I understood, you don't want to go on other page, so use return false, like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="javascript:triggerMe();return false;">click</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to return a false value if you want to abort the effect of href. Try using this code.

```
<a href="yourLink.com" title="my link" onclick="return triggerMe();"> Click me </a>
```

Javascript part

```
<script>
function triggerMe()
{
    if (condition) 
    {
        //do stuffs
        //This will tell browser to follow the link.
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        //do stuffs
        //This will cancel the default behaviour of the browser.
        //Abort the effect of href
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My best advice is to try using a **form** as follows:

First, change your href to:

```
<a href="#null" onclick="javascript:triggerMe()">click</a>
```

and add somewhere in your HTML code a form with a display=none button:

```
<form action="http://www.myhref.com"><button id="GoToHref" style="display:none"></button></form>
```

where action is your desired href. The onclick event calls the triggerMe() function. Change your function to include:

```
function triggerMe() {
    var DelayhrefCall;
    //include all code for what triggerMe() must do, then as the last line add
    DelayhrefCall = window.setTimeout(hrefCall, 500); 
    //500 millisecond delay, change time as desired
}
```

After a 500 ms delay, hrefCall() is called:

```
function hrefCall() {
document.getElementById('GoToHref').click();
}
```

The display:none button inside the form is then clicked, triggering the form's action, which takes you to your desired href. If you are linking to other pages on your site it works perfectly. If you are linking to external pages you will need to add a target to your form:

```
<form action="http://www.myhref.com" target="_blank"><button id="GoToHref"    
style="display:none"></button></form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a  onclick="javascript:triggerMe()" href="">click</a>
```

It will work

Answer (score -6):

```
 <a href="" onclick="return triggerme()" >click</a>
 function triggerme(e){
    if(condition is true){
       return true;
    } else {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }  
 }
```

Try this one will surely work

Comment: This has not a trace of jquery in it btw.